# Is the RFSH signal really needed in a Z80 CPU?

Tags: z80

The Z80 CPU has a RFSH (active low) signal used to signal when it's refresh time for dynamic RAM chips.

The Z80 datasheet states that RFSH alone shouldn't be used to generate a RAS only bus cycle in a DRAM, because at the time RFSH goes low, the address bus with the refresh address is not yet stable, so it is needed to wait for MREQ going low.

But during a refresh cycle, as MREQ goes low, neither RD or WR does so, making this the only bus cycle in which MREQ goes low but no read or write operation is signaled.

So, if the condition MREQ = 0 and RD = 1 and WR = 1 is enough to signal a refresh cycle, why Zilog engineers put that signal wasting a whole pin for it, when its function could be decoded with the already mentioned condition?

Comment: I think it is because the bus can be requested and owned, so that the Z80 is no longer in control of \$\overline{MREQ}\$, \$\overline{WR}\$, or \$\overline{RD}\$ (or address bus and other things.) Only the Z80 can initiate a refresh. If you decoded \$\overline{RFSH}\$ arbitrarily as you indicate, then this could be a problem when the bus isn't under control of the Z80. Or so it seems to me right now.

Comment: @jonk Please make this an answer.